# Recursive function to find position of number within a matrix

Tags: python, recursion

I have to make this small recursion exercise where, given a matrix and a number I have to return the position of the number in the matrix. For example:

```
matrix = [[2,0,1],[3,5,3],[5,1,4,9],[0,5]]
numberToFind = 5
```

The expected result would be this one:

```
[(1,1),(2,0),(3,1)]
```

Could anyone pint me on how to start or what I have to do to create the code?

Comment: Can you please share what you've tried and where do you have `specific` question?  Also, it's required to be `recursion` way to solve it?

Comment: Yes, it's required to be recursion. I haven't really tried anything because I have no idea where to start but I can give it a try.

Comment: Just start to solve it in the pen-and-paper, then try to find the `flow` or `pattern`.

Comment: I would say start by making an iterative version of the program first since that is usually easier. If you still have issues you can at least have a place you started from.

Comment: I have a recursive version, I'll try checking on that

Comment: what would be the output if you had a 5 in place of the 9?

Comment: It would be (2,3), count starts at 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach using a recursive generator:

```
matrix = [[2,0,1],[3,5,3],[5,1,4,9],[0,5]]
numberToFind = 5

def find(m, n, prev=tuple()):
    for i,x in enumerate(m):
        if isinstance(x, list):
            yield from find(x, n, prev=prev+(i,))
        elif x==n:
            yield prev+(i,)
            
list(find(matrix, numberToFind))
```

output: `[(1, 1), (2, 0), (3, 1)]`

other example:

```
matrix = [[2,0,1],[3,5,3],[5,1,4,5],[0,5],[[[2,5,[1,5]]]]]
list(find(matrix, numberToFind))

# [(1, 1), (2, 0), (2, 3), (3, 1), (4, 0, 0, 1), (4, 0, 0, 2, 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use just a single `for` loop as below. Way more efficient than a recursion

```
matrix = [[2,0,1],[3,5,3],[5,1,4,9],[0,5]]

my_list = []

for x in range(0,len(matrix)):
  try:
    a = matrix[x].index(5)
    my_list.append((x,a))
  except ValueError:
    pass
```

Comment: Yep I've tried something like this but I need to use recursion